# Has anybody used an EditText box and below that (below layer) a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I am trying to mark different lines in the EditText box with different (background) colors, i.e. line 1 - Blue, line 2 - Black etc. I achieve this by filling the color in the appropriate textbox in the background ListView. I am doing this as EditText doesn't provide a method by which the background color of only a line can be set (**anyone please provide a method if you know so**). Now whenever a user scrolls the EditText box I scroll the ListView also by the same amount, so that they move together and it feels like the EditText box lines are set with the corresponding background color.

The **only issue I face** is that when the ListView scrolls down/up, the new lines (in the ListView) that are revealed (those that were below the displayed lines) do not have any color set. It seems like ListView is not drawing the new lines (textboxes) that are getting revealed. Is this because ListView is in the background of EditText (I am using Relative Layout with ListView below and EditText on top)? Is there any way ListView can be made to fill correct color even when scrolling, for the new lines that get revealed?

### Thanks.

EDIT: Code as requested:
This is the entry in layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    >
    <ListView android:id="@+id/bgLv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/et1" android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="" android:gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/textbox_border"></EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT 2: Posting ListAdapter code:
Here b is the Boolean array, on checking which, the color of the line is decided.

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BackgroundListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private boolean b[];
    private Context context;

    BackgroundListAdapter(Context c, int a)
    {
        super(c,a);
        context = c;
    }
    BackgroundListAdapter(Context c, int a, int b)
    {
        super(c,a,b);
        context = c;
    }
    BackgroundListAdapter(Context c, int a, int b, List<String> l)
    {
        super(c,a,b,l);
        context = c;
    }
    BackgroundListAdapter(Context c, int a, int b, String[] s)
    {
        super(c,a,b,s);
        context = c;
    }
    BackgroundListAdapter(Context c, int a, List<String> l)
    {
        super(c,a,l);
        context = c;
    }
    BackgroundListAdapter(Context c, int a, String[] s)
    {
        super(c,a,s);
        context = c;
    }
    BackgroundListAdapter(Context c, boolean[] b)
    {
        super(c,R.layout.listview_background,new String[b.length]);
        context = c;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_background, null);
            rowView.setTag(new ViewHolder((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listBackgroundTV)));
        }

        ((ViewHolder)rowView.getTag()).tv.setHeight((position != 0)?((TextBox)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.ctb1)).getLineHeight():((TextBox)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.ctb1)).getLineHeight() + (int) (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f));
        ((ViewHolder)rowView.getTag()).tv.setBackgroundColor((b[position])?0xff000000:0xffffffff);

        return rowView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView tv;

    ViewHolder(TextView tv)
    {
        this.tv = tv;
    }
}
```

EDIT 3: onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et1.setText(inpStr);
    final ListView lv1 = ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.bgLv1));
    final BackgroundListAdapter bla = new BackgroundListAdapter(this,colorLines);
    lv1.setAdapter(bla);
}
```

Comment: Can you put some code up please.  It sounds like you could use the layoutBelow attribute in your layout.xml.

Comment: Hi Mark, please find the code updated above. Let me try using layoutBelow attribute - also, now that you can see the code, can you tell me how I can use the layoutBelow attribute and whether I need to use the layoutBelow attribute. Thanks.

Comment: Done see my answer below.

Comment: @MarkBasler I suppose layoutBelow is meant to set a view below, in the same plane. In my case the ListView is the background layer. And the EditText box is the layer above ListView. (I have made EditText box background transparent so that ListView can be seen). Can you provide some help after this information? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of doing that programmatically set them visible using    etLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
   btn_directions.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Then use the layout I have edited below.

Comment: Hi Mark, the layout_below attribute that you added, does it signify **view below in same plane** or does it signify **view as a layer below**? Thanks.

Comment: This will put the gui item below the other one you specified.  It has nothing to do with the plane.  This is all based on the layout of the gui.  Just try it and see if it works.

Comment: BTW, it seems I can't chat. I don't have enough reputation. Anyway thanks Mark for your replies. I hope you understood my problem scenario. If you read my question post as well as my comments you should be able to understand..

Comment: I do just try the answer below.

Comment: Nope, now the ListView background has disappeared altogether. This is what I am doing in my app: I use the ListView as the background of EditText. I achieve this by making background of EditText transparent, so that the ListView line colors can be seen and appear as the EditText's line background..

Comment: Ok do me a favor and post your java code for the listview.

Comment: Hi Mark, please check now.

Comment: That isn't the Async Task.  Did you call your webservice from a async task?

Comment: Actually I don't have a webservice. I just start an activity with this layout. Now when the user scrolls the EditText I make the ListView scroll as well. There is an initial activity, which then just starts this activity. That is it..

Comment: Oh my bad...to many posts hahaha

Comment: Ok I meant the activity .java file for the layout.xml file you posted.

Comment: In the activity java file, I just do this in its onCreate method: a. setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); b. Set text in EditText c. findViewbyId of ListView; d. Set adapter to ListView.

Comment: Can you put your onCreate method above.

Comment: So you want both to show up one on top of the other...Doesn't really sound like a visually appealing solution though.

Comment: But then how can I have different colors set for different lines (as background color) in EditText? For e.g. I want line 1 to be blue, but line 2 to be black?

Comment: You can create a custom xml file that will draw different colored lines.

Comment: Really!!! The hell how do I do it?

Comment: Have you looked it up or googled it.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the help. Can you also tell me how to include this as the line background color for my EditText? Thanks.

Comment: Mark Basler, can you help?

Comment: Mark Basler, if you tell me how to mark lines separately with the background color xml, I can mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I draw my rectangles for my table

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape= "rectangle"  >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Ok so how do I make this shape apply to a line in EditText? As background. Thanks.